# Why React-Semantic-UI Transition not animating the Component?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, react-transition-group

I am having a Component which is a `Modal` alert. For animating the Modal, I am using the `Transition` from semantic-ui-react. But only a few animations(`pulse`,`bounce`, `flash`) are working and that too only while mounting of Component, and not working while I close the `Modal`. Also the `duration` property is also not working.

```
class Alert extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: true
  };

  close = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;
    return (
      <Transition animation="fade" duration={1000} visible={open}>
        <Modal
          size="mini"
          closeOnDimmerClick={false}
          closeOnEscape={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.close}>

          <Modal.Content>
            <p>
              Hello user
            </p>
          </Modal.Content>
          <Modal.Actions>
            <Button color="blue" onClick={this.close}>
              Ok
            </Button>
          </Modal.Actions>
        </Modal>
      </Transition>
    );
  }
}
```

Why such weird behavior? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Modal` is unmounting way before `Transition` can animate it, one way would be to let Transition unmount the Modal:

```
class Alert extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: true
  };

  close = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;
    return (
      <Transition
        animation="fade"
        duration={1000}
        unmountOnHide={true}
        visible={open}
      >
        <Modal
          size="mini"
          closeOnDimmerClick={false}
          closeOnEscape={false}
          open={true}
          onClose={this.close}
        >
          <Modal.Content>
            <p>Hello user</p>
          </Modal.Content>
          <Modal.Actions>
            <Button color="blue" onClick={this.close}>
              Ok
            </Button>
          </Modal.Actions>
        </Modal>
      </Transition>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Alert]

I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes it worked. But, the Component never gets unmounted. I put the `componentWillUnmount` and it never gets called. Can you please try this.

Comment: `Alert` component won't unmount, `Modal` will get unmounted, `Transition` component should be mounted for it to be able to apply the transitions it its children. What do you want to do, do you need to execute some logic once the modal get closed? You could simply use `close` method you've already defined in the component.

Comment: I`Alert` component would be used by the application from anywhere. Would it be ok to let it be on the DOM, amd mounting/unmounting only the `Modal`?

Comment: It's OK. In fact, `Transition` component only mounts its children to the DOM, overriding their `className` to add transition css classes; nothing will be in the actual DOM if it has no children. Inspect the example I attached to the answer you'll see it by yourself.